# R3f. drei. Html elemnt has black,see trough other objets background

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using drei, Html helper to add some html elements on boxes. For some reason there appears some kind of black plane, which shows other html object behind other boxes. No idea how to fix it. It might be something to do with occlude, but without it you can see trough other boxes and see other html elements.  and  are from drei.

[image]
[image]

```
<Box args={[21, 23, 1]} position={[50,0,0]} rotation={[0,Math.PI / 2,0]} >
            <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="rgb(64, 64, 64)" />
            <Html 
                position={[0,0,0.6]}
                center
                transform
                occlude="blending"
        
            >
                <Skills />
            </Html>
        </Box>
```